# laravel spatie media library file not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I have installed and configured the laravel spatie media library. In the media table I have the first records which contain the first images.

I get this error in the console:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/public/2/shot.png 404 (Not Found)`

filesystems.php

```
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'photo' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/photo'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
```

i used this command

php artisan storage:link

blade file

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/app/public/' . $media->id . '/' . $media->file_name) }}" alt="{{ $media->name }}">
```

and controller

```
    $media = media::where('collection_name', 'photo')
    ->where('model_id', auth()->id())
    ->first();
```

Comment: Try: <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $media->id . '/' . $media->file_name) }}" alt="{{ $media->name }}">